# What can be done about gradle daemon not working with ClearCase?

Tags: java, gradle, daemon, clearcase

When I run my "gradle build" command in ClearCase in one view, wait for the command to finish, then switch to another view, and then run the same command in the second view, nothing works correctly, because the daemon doesn't work well with views. To get it to work correctly, I have to run "gradle --stop" every time I switch views (which is very frequently), or run "gradle --no daemon build", which defeats the purpose of having the daemon at all. Ultimately the worst part is just that occasionally I forget to kill the demon and then do a full clean build of our full software build (~15 minutes), before realizing I built the wrong codebase.

I'm not willing to get rid of the daemon entirely, because it has such a positive effect as long as I remain in one view, so I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this issue, or if it just comes down to the fact that the gradle daemon wasn't designed to work with ClearCase.

It seems to me that there should be some way to make daemons specific to a view, but perhaps that's never been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, the workaround would be to use [snapshot views instead of dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309) (which are using a [MVFS: MultiVersion FileSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172362/6309), a *virtual* filesystem)

You can checkout only part of the Vob, with loading rules, in order to not download *everything*.

A more complex approach would be to develop a gradle wrapper, as the one put in place to support another virtual filesystem based on FUSE: [`avasquez614/sec-cloud-fs`](https://github.com/avasquez614/sec-cloud-fs) (here [is the wrapper](https://github.com/avasquez614/sec-cloud-fs/commit/e183310cb21dceae748b192626542efe8a2d8b97))