# Cannot build using gradle when using clearcase

Tags: gradle, clearcase

I have been trying to build my Java web application using gradle. Everything work fine in the local drive and the build goes through as expected. However, when I switch to using the clearcase MVFS File system (G:), the build seems to behave erratically. From the windows 10 command line, if I change directory to the G:\ drive location, and execute "gradle war", it works fine the first time. After that, I run the same command again - the already created war file gets deleted and the classes are removed. It's bizarre. I did the following and still the behavior is the same.

1. disabled daemon
2. disabled file watching

Its the same behavior with Gradle 7 and gradle 6.8.

When I delete the .gradle folder, everything works fine again.

So - Does gradle not support the NFS and MVFS File System ? What is the solution to this problem ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does gradle not support the NFS and MVFS File System ?

That is why [I proposed in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49707216/6309) to use gradle only in snapshot views.
Especially considering a "`gradle --no-daemon build`" does defeat the purpose of having the daemon at all.

A build is better served in a local filesystem than a mounted one (MVFS dynamic views) which relies on where your view server is.

Comment: In my case, using the no-daemon flag also does not work. With the daemon not running, when I re-run the build, the war file and the classes are deleted for some strange reason. I expect nothing should happen because no files were changed. The output of the build command does say "UP-to-DATE" for the individual tasks - as expected. But somehow the outcome is just bizarre. The only way to recover is to remove the .gradle folder in the project and build again. I think snapshot view will work as you suggested. I wanted to ask if there is any way to use the Dynamic View or is it just a bad idea ?

Comment: @viraj For build, I often had issues with dynamic views, and no problem with snapshot. If possible, that is what I would use.